# Spring boot with or without sockjs?

Tags: spring-boot, flutter, websocket, spring-websocket

Im trying to make a chat app with spring and flutter and i was wondering if sockjs is really a big deal since these days every browser supports websockets and there is no need for fallbacks and also for me there is no sock js library in flutter .
So is sock js even useful in 2020 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your logic is correct, chrome and mostly all browsers use websockets now. Although you'd be loosing some functionality from sockjs but say for chat app it won't be needed

Comment: what are those functionalities?